# Problem in mapping logic with tuple implicit conversion "Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] storage ref."

Tags: solidity

I am creating a raffle where people can buy tickets, and the tickets index are stored at their address for the future draw logic.

I have a problem at the buyTicket function, with the logic `addressToTickets[msg.sender] = tickets.push(ticketId);`

I want it to push the ticketId to the addressToTickets mapping in the tickets array.
However, it returns "Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] storage ref."

What should I do to correctly add the tickets index to an array associated with every address?

```
   uint public ticketPrice = 100 * 10 ** 18;
   uint ticketId;
   address public dao; 
   mapping(uint => address) public ticketToAddress;
   mapping(address => uint[]) public addressToTickets;

   uint[] public tickets;


function buyTicket(uint256 prixUnitaire, uint256 quantity) external returns (uint) {      
    require((prixUnitaire * quantity) == (ticketPrice * quantity), "Not the good price"); 

    transfer(dao, (10 * 10 ** 18 * quantity));
    transfer(address(this), (90 * 10 ** 18 * quantity));

    for(uint i = quantity; i >= 1; i--) {
        addressToTickets[msg.sender] = tickets.push(ticketId);
        ticketToAddress[ticketId] = msg.sender; 
    ticketId++;
    }

    return ticketId;
}
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: @AdriRo What solc version are you using? In versions 0.5.xx and older `push(something)` returns the new array's length, since 0.6.xx and newer it returns nothing.

Comment: It is version 0.8.xx ! Otherwise it is all the contract code. I realized indeed the problem is at ```addressToTickets[msg.sender] = tickets.push(ticketId);```  as it returns nothing and can't be marked as equality. 

    It was succesfully refactored as ```for(uint i = quantity; i >= 1; i--) {
        addressToTickets[msg.sender].push(ticketId);
        ticketToAddress[ticketId] = msg.sender; 
        ticketId++;
        } ```